# Express: calling next() after json() - Middlewares

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-headers, middleware

Building a REST API with NodeJs and Express: my goal is to implement the 2 simplest `Middlewares`:

1. The first one is going to log the incoming request
2. The second one is going to log the processed response (which is a `JSON`)

#### The first middleware *(in app.js)*

```
function logReqMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  log.info('>>> %s at %s', req.method, req.path);
  next();
}
```

#### The second middleware *(in app.js)*

```
function logResponseMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  log.info('<<< %s (%s)', JSON.stringify(res), res.status);
  next();
}
```

#### The controller function *(in apiController.js)*

```
export var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', foo);

function foo(req, res, next) {
  res.status(200).json({ stupidExample: true });
  next();
}
```

#### Building the app *(app.js)*

```
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(logReqMiddleware);
app.use('/api', apiController.router);
app.use(logResponseMiddleware);
var server = app.listen(3000, function(){ log.info('running'); });
```

Now, making a request at `localhost:3000/api` says: `can't set headers after they are sent`; [this is the related super cool response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent) my question is, is it incompatible to write json data with `json()` and adding the second middleware? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `next()` inside `logResponseMiddleware`. There's nothing else to do, so calling `next()` is probably sending you into express's default 404 handler which is trying to respond with a default status and body.

Aside: `JSON.stringify(res)` is not what you want. `res` is an object instance representing the response (lots of methods, internal state properties, etc). It is not the response body content string. As the `res` is a writeable stream, it's not going to keep the response body content around for you to log, it's just going to try to send it over the HTTP connection.

Comment: Any way to inspect the body content of the ```res``` or just impossible?

Comment: I don't think it's straightforward to do it generically after the fact like you are hoping. The pragmatic thing to do is to log it just before you write it to the `res`, but that's harder to centralize. You could store it on the `res` in a custom property like `res.bodyJson` and then centrally log it and write to the `res`, but overall the API here is not conducive to your goal.